# How to initialize the count in a Map of enums?

Tags: java, enums, java-8, java-stream

Problem: I'd like a resulting map to contain all available `enums`, and if not found in the iterated list, be preinitialized with `long = 0`.

```
List<Basket> basket;

Map<TypeOfGoods, Long> counts = basket.stream
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Basket::getGoodsType, Collectors.counting()));

enum TypeOfGoods {
    FRUITS, TOYS;
}
```

In this example, the map will only contain the types that are actually found in the basket, but missing any other enums. How could I also include these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative would be to use `putIfAbsent`:

```
Map<TypeOfGoods, Long> counts = basket.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Basket::getGoodsType, counting()));

Arrays.asList(TypeOfGoods.values()).forEach(e -> counts.putIfAbsent(e, 0L));
```

Comment: That's one ugly closure ;-)

Comment: @JeanLogeart What's ugly?

Comment: ``forEach`` here is just a side effect call actually inserting elements in a variable created outside the lambda. It is kind of a hack of ``forEach``. It looks very imperative, and not really functional. Yet it works perfectly well and is also very readable so it is not a bad solution :)

Comment: @JeanLogeart Well  `putAll` has also a side-effect as you also modify `counts`. ;-) It's Java so even with its new features you cannot always avoid side-effects, as the API collection is not designed to be as it anyway...

Comment: Not really, it is what putAll does. But I agree with you one the second point.

Comment: @JeanLogeart Ah I see what you mean, yeah it's designed like that but I was speaking more in a functional perspective as it modifies the map in place it can be considered as having a side-effect, otherwise it would have been `counts = counts.putAll(...);`, but yeah, it's Java.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It still looks way better than the non stream way!

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
Map<TypeOfGoods, Long> counts = Arrays.stream(TypeOfGoods.values())
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(identity(), x -> 0L));
counts.putAll(basket.stream
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Basket::getGoodsType, Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: Where is `constant()` function? Still couldn't find it.